# LeetCode TwoSum question returning buggy answer (C Implementation)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Here is the question:

```
Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

You can return the answer in any order
```

Here is my solution for the same:

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    
    int* result= (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    int* iterator= nums;
    int sum=0;
    
    for (int i=0; i<numsSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<numsSize; j++)
        {
            if (i!=j)
            { 
                sum=iterator[i]+iterator[j];
                if (sum==target)
                {
                    result[0]=i;
                    result[1]=j;
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;

}
```

I know that it is not the most optimal solution, but I assumed it would work. LeetCode shows me that the answer returned is `[]` or `]`.
It seems to work fine on VSCode. I was wondering if I could get some help regarding what the error might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the number of elements of the array to return (`2` in this case) to what the argument `returnSize` points at (`*returnSize`) to tell the judge system how large the array you returned is.